# joomla website without access to central server - is it possible?

Tags: joomla

I want to develop a website in an existing domain name, say http://www.example.com/~username/
I have access only to my domain.
Is there any way I can create a joomla website?
In other words, do I have to ask people in the main server to install joomla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download joomla from [here](http://www.joomla.org/download.html) and upload it your your ftp. Then go your your website address which will take you through the installation process. If you do not have access to your server, then you will have to ask whoever does.